# Projection problem - ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, layers, geotiff-tiff

I have multiple .tif files downloaded from Ortho Downloader for an Aerial View of Ward 21 in Saint Louis City, MO.  I need the .tif files to underlay my layer depicting the boundaries of Ward 21 as well as the parcels within Ward 21.

The .tif layers come projected to `NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_Missouri_East_FIPS_2401_Feet`.  My parcel layer and Ward layer are both projected to `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Missouri_East_FIPS_2401_Feet`.  And yet when both are added to the same blank ArcMap fullscreen view shows them as projected at different locations - the .tif files on the right and the rest of my St Louis layers on the left, separated by several inches of space.  I have tried Geographic Transformations, Projecting each layer to 1983 again, and restarting my computer.  It will not let me project the .tif files (they simply don't show up in the Input options for Project).  I cannot figure out how to make these things lay on top of each other.  Please help!

Comment: Which one appears in the correct location when compared to a third source of geospatial data, for example, a basemap? Odds are that the other has the wrong projection assigned.

Comment: Have you turn off the "on the fly projection?" and see what happens ?

Comment: You can, of course, project the rasters using Project Raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007q000000 (the Project tool is for vector which is why you can't select a raster) but I don't advise it. It sounds like one of your datasets is in the wrong spatial reference as Bjorn suggests so you would want to use Define Projection http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000 to reset the one that is incorrect before projecting to your chosen spatial reference.

Comment: If you can, please post the extents of the two sets of data. If they're in feet, the x values should be around 900000, y around 1million. If they're in meters, x around 213k, y around 300k.

Comment: @Bjorn - the basemap (that is, the .tif file) is on the right, while everything else shows up on the left.  When I adjust from 1927 to 1983 or the reverse, it still shows up on the left, just slightly higher or lower.

Comment: @mkennedy - the extents are (left to right): 573363.35 x 1021881.89 Feet and 895919.052 x 1034287.878 Feet

Comment: @PROBERT - I turned off on the fly projection by going to View > Data Frame Properties > Coordinates > (globe image) > Clear, and then put in an "unknown source" layer and defined the layer as NAD_1983_StatePlane_Missouri_East_FIPS_2401_Feet, and it again projected to the left of the basemap.  Was that what you meant, or did I do it wrong?

Comment: @T.Kerr  -  Yes. to see if they overlap or not... Did they overlap or not ?

Comment: Have you figure it out the problem ?

Comment: @T.Kerr so that dataset had the correct extents. How about the other dataset?

Comment: @PROBERT - Nope.  Still one to the right and one to the left.

Comment: Have you tried other areas and download them  with .tif to see if they have the same results as the ones you already download ? Sometimes people forgot to put the right projection and that can cause pain. If you download it and check what their projection is and if you see different than the ones you had then there is a problem...

Comment: Do you have the website that you can show us and perhaps one of us can help you out....

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by going back to a prior Ortho Download, adding the .tif layers to that, and then adding in everything else.  It worked, none of the projections changed for any of the layers (including all the ones I used the first time).  I hate projections. Why don't they make consistent sense?